# Why isn't /etc/rc.local executed when I log in?

Tags: linux, scripting, linux-mint

I'm trying to run a script at login, and this is the way I've found to do it.

I'ved edited `/etc/rc.local` with a line such as `bash /home/me/script.sh`.

I've made that script executable.

It doesn't seem that my command is being executed upon login. What steps could I take to debug this?

My distro is Linux Mint 12 running Gnome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`/etc/rc.local` is executed at **boot**, not during login.  If you want to run something at login, you'd normally put it in `~/.profile` or `~/.bash_profile`.  For GUI applications, Gnome has a Startup Applications tool.

Or did you mean "boot" when you said "login"?